# how should i create my own 'now' / DateTime.Now?

Tags: c#

i'm starting to build a part of a system which will hold a lot of DateTime validations, and a lot of 'if it was done before now' or 'if it will start in an hour etc'.

Usual way to go is to use **DateTime.Now** to get the **actual time**.

I predict however, that during unit test that will give me a real headache because i will have to setup my testdata for the time when the test will run in stead of use a default set of test data.
So i thought: why not use my own 'now' so i can set the current datetime to any moment in time.
As i don't want to set the testservers internal clock i was thinking about this solution, and i was wondering what you think of it.
Base thought is that i use my own DateTime class.
That class gives you the current datetime, but you can also set your own time from outside.

```
 public static class MyDateTime
    {
        private static TimeSpan _TimeDifference = TimeSpan.Zero;
        public static DateTime Now
        {
            get
            {
                return DateTime.Now + _TimeDifference;
            }
        }
        public static void SetNewNow(DateTime newNow)
        {
            _TimeDifference = newNow - DateTime.Now;
        }
        public static void AddToRealTime(TimeSpan timeSpan )
        {
            _TimeDifference =  timeSpan;
        }
        public static void SubtractFromRealTime(TimeSpan timeSpan)
        {
            _TimeDifference =  - timeSpan;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what's wrong with the Framework's DateTime built-in methods?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425721/unit-testing-datetime-now

Comment: I'd avoid calling it `MyDateTime`, too easy to mistake for `DateTime`, better to call it something easier to distinguish.

Comment: @Mitch i wouldn't know how to reset the datetime.now ?

Comment: @mark i agree, but most answers go directly to a framework. we're not using a mock framework right now, and i can't introduce an entire mocking framework (even if i use just a part of it) just for this unit tests.

Comment: @Michel: Who said anything about a mocking framework? The answer provided to the other question defaults to using the static DateTime property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some time ago i already read something about it. A short search for **mock DateTime.Now** with your favorite search engine should reveal enough links.

This seems to look quite interesting:
http://blog.typemock.com/2009/05/mockingfaking-datetimenow-in-unit-tests.html

Comment: isn't that a paid product?
besides that, i'm a little resistant to implement/use a whole new framework of which i don't know anything for this small functionality.

Answer (score 0):

what do u mean ? 
if u need any specialization, so u can use Extension methods !
easily write an extension method for DateTime class and do whatever u need.

Comment: that is true, but also the extension method has to have some code?