# DateTime provider to using and mocking

Tags: c#

I writing unit tests for project and in code is a lot references to DateTime.Now. It's bad practice right? Because hosting can be in different time zone as developing.

So I trying to make a useful TimeProvider to using in dayily coding and what can be mocked.

I have made that:

```
 interface ITimePrivder
    {
        DateTime Now { get; }
        DateTime UtcNow { get; }
        string TimeZone { get; }
    }
    class TimeProvider : ITimePrivder
    {
        public virtual DateTime Now => DateTime.Now;
        public virtual DateTime UtcNow => DateTime.UtcNow;
        public virtual string TimeZone
        {
            get
            {
                lock(this._object)
                {
                int difference = DateTime.Now.Hour - DateTime.UtcNow.Hour;
                string timeZone = (difference >= 0) ? $"+{difference}" : $"-{difference}";
                return timeZone;
            }
            } 
        }
        private object _object = new object();

    }
```

What do you think? It's useful? Can I using it in my ASP.NET MVC and Console projects safety?

Is now theard safe?

Comment: Take a look at http://nodatime.org/. I believe it also supports mocks for unit tests.

Comment: Definitely useful. Better use DateTimeOffset class. And why do you use locking here?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you are using `DateTime.Now`, but if business logic depends on it and you want to unit test this logic you solution is quite good.

Some other thought oh this matter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425721/unit-testing-datetime-now) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ploeh/archive/2007/05/12/testingagainstthecurrenttime.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

One good strategy is to use one timezone throughout the application, for example GMT. Here you can find more information about datetime provider : [Unit Testing: DateTime.Now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425721/unit-testing-datetime-now)