# not able to unittest method that uses HostingEnvironment.MapPath (.net)

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I have to unittest one method that uses appSettings to get `filename`, that is later used inside `HostingEnvironment.MapPath`.

BLL method to test contains the following line where _appSettings.SampleName return some filename in Web project. Later filePath is used to open given file.

```
string filePath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(_appSettings.SampleName);     
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    ...
```

In UnitTesting project I have the following structure:

```
<UnitTestProject.Test>\Resources\MyFile.xlsx
```

In my unittest I was able to mock _appSettings (_appSettings: IAppSettings) and I can set _appSettings.SampleName any value I wish. This value is really taken inside method I am testing. However, I tried to set _appSettings.SampleName to "Resources\MyFile.xlsx" as well as other values like @"....\Resources\MyFile.xlsx".

However, I always get `filePath = null`.

Someone marked that htis is duplicate: [Unit Testing: DateTime.Now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425721/unit-testing-datetime-now), but I do not need to Mock this method. I have already mocked appsettings, but I am not able to understand why HostingEnvironment.MapPath doesn't work as I want. I am mocking appsettings returing path I wish, but HostingEnvironmentm.MapPath doesn't work. THus probably I do not understand how HostingEnvironment works.

Comment: You have not understood my question, I am not asking how to unittest static method, I know how to mock it, but I cannot mock it with desired value. Always when I mock it wish new value, I cannot get it to go to desired folder. Morover, I have to write unitttest, I am not able to change existing code.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I am sorry, I do not understand how example with DateTime helps me in my case.

Comment: Probably behaves like that because there is no hosting environment when running the tests. You need to mock this out.

Comment: Reopened. Since you already know all ways to mock static method it sounds like you need good explanation of MapPath... Consider checking out source code -I don't think there are many people familiar with such details. Most would go with changing code or some heavy weight framework like moles (whatever it is currently called)