# Set readonly DateTime.UtcNow to some other date

Tags: c#

I know this sounds so silly. But I want to set the **readonly** field **DateTime.UtcNow** to **01/01/2021**. is it possible?
I have an existing application where we have used **DateTime.UtcNow** heavily. Now the client wants to process the old files. 
But we can't change the code in so many places and retest all over again. I was wondering if it's possible to set the **DateTime.UtcNow** value to a past date so that code will not be impacted.

Please advice. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36452202/3181933). Realistically, you should change the code instead.

Comment: When you do change it, make dates and times an injected service. It makes testing (and what you are talking about) simpler

Comment: Why would you need to test less if you would change code from UtcNow to something else compared to manipulating UtcNow to be something else, in both cases you change the date don't see the difference to be honest.