# For .net 8, how can I fix The type or namespace name 'TimeProvider' could not be found?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I found a demo to use the new .Net 8 TimeProvider class.

I installed the .Net 8 Preview.

But when I try to run the demo, code below, I get an error message: the type or namespace name 'TimeProvider' could not be found

Not sure what step I am missing.

```
private readonly TimeProvider _timeProvider;

public GreeterService(TimeProvider timeProvider)
{
    _timeProvider = timeProvider;
}
```

I found the source code here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/83604/files/a30d9629eaa94431a34cc6cb665cf289b6a8ebc9#diff-e0027dab3fd834f49597f445c9108c3f5a9570e4c2d66c8cf428d024ab61aff2

I also found this post: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/47472

Comment: Do you also set your <TargetFramework> correctly?

Comment: It looks like I did. It is set to net8.0

Comment: Yes, I did.  But, I don't think that is my issue.

Comment: Is there any update about this issue? Since it's not released yet, how do you use it.

Comment: TimeProvider is in preview.4 so you need to download the code from dotnet/installers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my research, the latest release date of .Net 8.0.0-preview.2 is March 14, 2023.

[image]

This release is currently only available on Visual Studio 2022 (v17.6 Preview 1).

The update in your link has not been released yet, please wait for the next release.